# Read string and various integers in same line in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have a string called `buffer` which has the following data stored:
*Rb [7, 0] 64*

Using `sscanf()`, I'd like to do the following:

- Read `Rb` and store it in a `string` called `name`
- Read `7` and store it in an `int` variable called `posx`
- Read `0` and store it in an `int` variable called `posy`
- Read `64` and store it in a `int` variable called `battery_level`

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%s[^\ ] [%d,%d] %d", name, &posx, &posy, &battery_level);
```

Comment: @user3121023 I had already tried that but for some reason it doesn't work. When I try to printf(" %s, %d, %d, %d", name, posx, posy, battery_level); nothing happens.

Comment: @user3121023 had tried that too, but doesn't work either..

Answer (score 2):

Problems that I see:

1. `"\ "` is not a valid escape sequence.
2. `"%s[^ ]"` does not do what you are expecting it to do. You need to use `"%[^ ]"`.

You can use

```
sscanf(buffer, "%s [%d,%d] %d", name, &posx, &posy, &battery_level);
```

or

```
sscanf(buffer, "%[^ ] [%d,%d] %d", name, &posx, &posy, &battery_level);
```

Both of them work. See working code at http://ideone.com/QNuQuY

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when I compile it in code blocks.. Gonna see what's wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that it helps you.

I wrote a code, where the inputs will be divided by the first space `' '` sign, you can use other characters also, and improving this logic you can get your desired result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char buffer[] = "Rb [7, 0] 64";
    int posx, posy, batttery_level
    sscanf(buffer, "%[^ ] [%d,%d] %d", name, &posx, &posy, &battery_level);
    printf("%s [%d,%d] %d\n", name, posx, posy, battery_level);
    return 0;
}
```